# connect java to mysql using jdbc on osx

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mamp

So I added the MySQL Connector/J 5.1.16 to my project's Build Path. I'm using the default OSX Java package and MAMP Pro 1.9.4 with MySQL 5.1.44 and Eclipse.

I've set up a simple java app with the following function:

```
private static String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mpp";
private static String dbUsername = "root";
private static String dbPassword = "root";

private Statement statement = null;

private void dbConnect() {


try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);
    statement = connection.createStatement();

} catch(SQLException e) {
    System.err.print(e.getMessage() + " ARGH!");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.print(e.getMessage() + " FUUUUUUUUUU!");
}
}
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. ARGH!
```

I googled and searched for about an hour with no success. Any ideas on how to fix this? The JDBC driver should be fine, I kinda tested it.

**EDIT**

I tried running this through the console

```
SnowCave:src stefanschipor$ java -cp $CLASSPATH test
```

I get the same output as above

Comment: Maybe a firewall problem. Is dbUrl correct? Can you connect to MySQL by some client console?

Comment: in your case defaut port localhost:3306

Comment: @Farshid updated the post, same thing :)

Comment: No, I mean connecting to MySQL instance without your code.

Comment: yup, it works. the mysql exec is in the MAMP folder but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, this is just silly. :)

You have open up MAMP, go to Server > MySQL and uncheck "Allow local access only" which is checked by default. This is weird since what I'm doing is local, but anyways...

My program seems to work and the commands suggested by @JamesA also yield the expected output!

Huzzah!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for posting the solution!

Comment: It could be you are using the wrong port in the JDBC connection. For example, if you are using MAMP, the port could be 8889 instead. This is the exact problem I had, hope it's helpful.

Comment: On MAMP PRO 3.3, you have to *check* "Allow network access to MySql" and choose "only from this Mac".

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure MySQL is running on port 3306?

---

If the mysql daemon is listening on port 3306 `lsof -i :3306` should return:

```
COMMAND  PID        USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  7616    username   10u  IPv6 0x1fbf6940      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

---

A direct connect to the port using `nc localhost 3306` should return:

```
H
5.5.969]G.Mw4??9cfUY?k!^:D&mysql_native_password
```

where `5.5.969` is the mysql version number.

---

You could also try a tool like [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com) to test your connection URL.

Comment: I had the Firewall turned off, but I enabled it and allowed Java anyway. Still the same :)

Comment: I ran the command in Terminal but I got no output. However, the port should be fine, here's a screenshot of my MAMP config http://grab.by/ahFv

Comment: What's your output from `lsof -i :3306`?

Comment: That means MySQL's not listening on port 3306.  Check the error log at `/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err`

Comment: Your error log looks correct.  The only items left to suggest is to see if there's anything related in your `/var/log/appfirewall.log` and to try re-installing MAMP.

Comment: Nothing there, as I had my firewall always turned off :) Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @GreenDude if the reinstall of MAMP works or you find another solution be sure and let us know for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the Port localhost:8889 or whatever port you find in MAMP > Settings > Ports > MySQL-Port.
Then your Connection will succeed!

Answer (score 0):

I also have this mysterious error on OSX and didn't found any solution the first time the error occurred. In my cases it occurs if the database structure was modified or tables were dropped/created during development (MySQL as a Datasource for JBoss). In all cases I can avoid the error if I shut down MySQL after modifications and restart it before JBoss starts.

Comment: Restarted MAMP, still no luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Its just because your `mysql` service is not running... just run the `mysql` service from system preferences or if you have installed it using `brew` run `brew services start mysql`