# How to add permission on MySQL Server on mac?

Tags: java, mysql, macos

Can you please tell me how to add permissions on MySQL server for Mac?

I am making a simple program for which I want to add a permission on MySQL server.  From a search on Google, I found:

> In MySQL Workbench go to the "Server" menu heading and select "Users and Privileges". You can add a user here by clicking the"Add Account" button in the bottom left of the screen

Actually I am getting the same error 
[connect java to mysql using jdbc on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237860/connect-java-to-mysql-using-jdbc-on-osx)
But I am not using **MAMP**

I just download mysql connector jar file and 
mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64.dmg (mysql server)
mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.47-osx-i686(workbench).

Where is the server option in Workbench?

Comment: To be clear, when you say "sql server" you mean "MySQL"?  [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sql) is a competing RDBMS product from Microsoft.

Comment: yes ..i download from this http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: yes I install all software and workbench ..but i don't seeany server menu option on top bar

Comment: if you have workbench please send image of server(option) ..so that i will apply